# Tensorflow image reading empty

Tags: tensorflow

This question is based on: [Tensorflow image reading & display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648322/tensorflow-image-reading-display)

Following their code we have the following:

```
string = ['/home/user/test.jpg']
filepath_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(string)
self.reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = self.reader.read(filepath_queue)

print(value)
# Output: Tensor("ReaderRead:1", shape=TensorShape([]), dtype=string)

my_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value, channels=3)
print(my_img)
# Output: Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(3)]), dtype=uint8)
```

Why does `my_img` have no dimensions? (Dimension(3) is only because of the argument `channels=3`)

Does this mean that the image is not properly loaded? (`img = misc.imread('/home/user/test.jpg')` does load that image).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image will be properly loaded, but TensorFlow doesn't have enough information to infer the image's shape until the op is run. This arises because [`tf.image.decode_jpeg()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/image.html#decode_jpeg) can produce tensors of different shapes (heights and widths), depending on the contents of the string tensor `value`. This enables you to build [input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) using a collection of images with different sizes.

The `Dimension(None)` in the shape means ["unknown" rather than "empty"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Dimension.value).
If you happen to know that all images read by this operation will have the same size, you can use [`Tensor.set_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.set_shape) to provide this information, and doing so will help to validate the shapes of later parts of the graph:

```
my_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value, channels=3)    
KNOWN_HEIGHT = 28
KNOWN_WIDTH = 28
my_img.set_shape([KNOWN_HEIGHT, KNOWN_WIDTH, 3])

print(my_img)
# Output: Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(28), Dimension(28), Dimension(3)]), dtype=uint8)
```