# tensorflow check image is in reader

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I'm not sure whether TensorFlow actually has actually decoded an image when the output is only: `Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]), dtype=uint8)`

**How can I show the image and label from the Tensor object?**

(code partly from: [Tensorflow read images with labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340489/tensorflow-read-images-with-labels))

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from os.path import join

KNOWN_HEIGHT = 812
KNOWN_WIDTH = 812

def read_my_file_format(self, filename_and_label_tensor):
    """Consumes a single filename and label as a ' '-delimited string.

    Args:
      filename_and_label_tensor: A scalar string tensor.

    Returns:
      Two tensors: the decoded image, and the string label.
    """
    filename, label = tf.decode_csv(filename_and_label_tensor, [[""], [""]], ",")
    file_contents = tf.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_contents)
    #image.set_shape([KNOWN_HEIGHT, KNOWN_WIDTH, 3])

    return image, label

string = ['test.jpg,m', 'test2.jpg,f']
filepath_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(string)

image, label = read_my_file_format(filepath_queue.dequeue())

print(image)
# Output: Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]), dtype=uint8)

print(label)
# Output: Tensor("DecodeCSV:1", shape=TensorShape([]), dtype=string)
```

What can I do to show the actual image in `image` and also show the `label`? Because whether the image is indeed in the same folder or not doesn't change the output from `image` and `label`.

### Edit

The following code (partly from: [Tensorflow image reading & display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648322/tensorflow-image-reading-display)) shows an image on my friends Mac, but not on my Ubuntu 14.04:

```
# Test show image
images = []
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Start populating the filename queue.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    if len(string) > 0:
      for i in range(len(string)):
        plaatje = result.image.eval()
        images.append(plaatje)

    Image._showxv(Image.fromarray(np.asarray(plaatje)))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    print("tf.session success")
```

and this results in the following **error**:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1076] 0x7fa3940cb950 Compute status: Cancelled: Enqueue operation was cancelled
 [[Node: input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueMany[Tcomponents=[DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer, input_producer/RandomShuffle)]]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:278] Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt
```

Comment: Can you update your question with any of the other logs containing "Compute status: ..."? The "Cancelled" error is typically a symptom of an earlier error in the queue running thread. (For example, if the file were not found, you would see this error.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is code omitted in your second code section, no?

Try the solution suggested [here](http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/133267887103/tensorflow-placeholder-queue-errors). You have to initialize the placeholders before you start the queue runner. That fixed a similar problem for me.

And I guess you already figured out that you must call `.eval()` over your tensor in order to get its actual value. Look in this [question I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/tensorflow-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-python)