# tensorflow import images code does not work correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using [TensorFlow image reading & display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648322/tensorflow-image-reading-display/34985237#34985237)

I ran the above code which works correctly on the first run.
I have only one jpg file < 1MB.
Subsequent runs just hang; any idea or input?

Comment: When you are using queues, the read will hang at the end until more stuff is pushed onto the queue or the queue is closed...so perhaps reader.read is not closing the queue and waiting?

Comment: Can you share the exact code that you ran? The most likely reason for a hang is the absence of [`tf.train.start_queue_runners()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/train.html#start_queue_runners).