# Incorporating very large constants in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

For example, the [comments](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/im2txt/im2txt/data/build_mscoco_data.py#L73) for the Tensorflow image captioning example model state:

```
NOTE: This script will consume around 100GB of disk space because each image
in the MSCOCO dataset is replicated ~5 times (once per caption) in the output.

This is done for two reasons:

1. In order to better shuffle the training data.
2. It makes it easier to perform asynchronous preprocessing of each image in
TensorFlow.
```

The primary goal of this question is to see if there is an alternative to this type of duplication. In my use case, storing the data in this way would require each image to be duplicated in the TFRecord files many more times, on the order of 20 - 50 times.

I should note first that I have already fed the images through VGGnet to extract 4096 dim features, and I have these stored as a mapping between filename and the vectors.

Before switching over to Tensorflow, I had been feeding batches containing filename strings and then looking up the corresponding vector on a per-batch basis. This allows me to store all of the image data in ~15GB without needing to duplicate the data on disk.

My first attempt to do this in in Tensorflow involved storing indices in the TFExample buffers and then doing a "preprocessing" step to slice into the corresponding matrix:

```
img_feat = pd.read_pickle("img_feats.pkl")
img_matrix = np.stack(img_feat)
preloaded_images = tf.Variable(img_matrix)
first_image = tf.slice(preloaded_images, [0,0], [1,4096])
```

However, in this case, Tensorflow disallows a variable larger than 2GB. So my next thought was to partition this across several variables:

```
img_tensors = []
for i in range(NUM_SPLITS):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        img_tensors.append(tf.Variable(img_matrices[i], name="preloaded_images_%i"%i))

first_image = tf.concat(1, [tf.slice(t, [0,0], [1,4096//NUM_SPLITS]) for t in img_tensors])
```

In this case, I'm forced to store each partition on a separate graph, because it seems any one graph cannot be this large either. However, now the `concat` fails because each tensor I am concatenating is on a separate graph.

Any advice on incorporating a large amount (~15GB) of preloaded into the Tensorflow graph.

Potentially related is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648322/tensorflow-image-reading-display); however in this case I'd like to override the decoding of the actual JPEG file with the preprocessed value in a tensor op.

Comment: GraphDef has to be <2GB, so total size of constants has to be <2GB. However, tensors and variables are not stored in graphdef and can be larger.